# S3 method for `names()` or `c()`

Tags: r, methods

Is it possible to create an s3 method for the functions `c()` or `names()`?   In particular for an S3 class called 'foo', creating functions called `names.foo`, and `c.foo` seem to have no effect on concatenation and/or naming of S3 objects.

Comment: Looks to me that `names` and `c` are both generic. Did you use `setClass` or `setOldClass` first?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This 'works for me', e.g.,

```
> names.foo = function(x) "names.foo"
> names(structure(list(), class="foo"))
[1] "names.foo"
```

Also

```
> `names<-.foo` = function(x, value) { attr(x, "names") = value; x }
> f = structure(list(1:3), class='foo')
> f = structure(list(1:3), class='foo')
> names(f) = "bill"
> f
$bill
[1] 1 2 3

attr(,"class")
[1] "foo"
```

`setClass()` or `setOldCLass()` would be relevant in S4-land, but not for S3.

Comment: Thanks, @Martin.  Seems forgot to `#' @export` the names method from my package.